# How to make popup only invoke when form is actually submitted javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following form:

```html
<form action="/signup" method="post" class="register-form">
  <div>
    <div class="form-element">
      <label class="form-label" for="name">Name</label>
      <input class="form-input-text" type="text" name="name" value="" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
      <label class="form-label" for="email">E-Mail</label>
      <input class="form-input-text" type="email" autocomplete="email" name="email" value="" required>
    </div>
    <button class="form-button" type="submit" name="submit">Register</button>

  </div>
</form>
```

I built a little popup that says thanks for signing up that should come up after the user has entered his data. However at the moment I have the problem that it also comes up when the user clicks the register button without entering any data (meaning the request does not fire due to the required tags in the fields). How do I make the popup only come up when the form is actually submitted?

Jquery for the popup:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $(".form-button").click(function() {
        $('.popup').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event is an event you can listen to to trigger the popup. However you may want to consider of this is the best user experience; I believe opening the popup will prevent the form from being transmitted to the server until the popup is closed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply define `ids` on your each `input` to validate if both fields have value in it or not. Do like this

```
<form action="/signup" method="post" class="register-form">
  <div>
    <div class="form-element">
      <label class="form-label" for="name">Name</label>
      <input class="form-input-text" type="text" name="name" value="" id="text1">
    </div>
   <div class="form-element">
     <label class="form-label" for="email">E-Mail</label>
     <input class="form-input-text" type="email" autocomplete="email" name="email" value="" id="text2">
   </div>
   <button class="form-button" type="submit" name="submit">Register</button>
  </div>
</form>

$(window).load(function() {

   $(".form-button").click(function() {
      let input1 = $('#text1').val();
      let input2 = $('#input2').val();
      if(input1 && input2){
         //make your http req and then after getting your response open your popup
         $('.popup').show();
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the .submit event.

Using your example

```
$('.register-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop the form submitting
    $('.popup').show(); // Show the popup
    e.currentTarget.submit(); // Now submit it!
});
```

Comment: Please read question carefully. He wants his popup to show only after entering the data in fields. So it means he has to check for the values being inserted in input boxes or not.

Comment: It doesn't look like the onsubmit event gets fired if the required input doesn't have any value